# Change kendoDatePicker value from kendoNumeric control

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I have been struggling with KendoUI/Knockout integration.

My requirement:

1. Have two KendoUI DatePicker elements (Start and End date). End date should be readonly and should be a calculated value
2. A KendoUI NumericTextBox element(Period) to capture month values
3. When NumericTextBox value is inserted, it should automatically add on to the month value of the End date

My Attempt(please ignore use of tables):

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Start Date:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="StartDate" id="StartDate" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: eventStartDate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>End Date:</td>
        <td>
            <input name="EndDate" id="EndDate" data-bind="kendoDatePicker: computedEndDate" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event Period(months) :</td>
        <td>
            <input id="EventtPeriod" name="EventPeriod" data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: eventPeriod" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript/ViewModel(with my dysfunctional code commented out):

```
    var ViewModel = function () {
        var now = new Date();

        this.eventStartDate = ko.observable(now);
        this.eventPeriod = ko.observable();
        this.computedEndDate = ko.observable( );

        /* //DOES NOT WORK
        this.computedEndDate = ko.computed(function () {
            var start = $('#StartDate').data('kendoDatePicker').value();
            var period = $('#EndDate').data('kendoNumericTextBox').value()
            var end = $('#EndDate').data('kendoDatePicker')
            end.value.setMonth(start.getMonth() + period);
            //var eventPe
            //return end;
        });
        */
    };

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/user919426/JkgY6/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using Knockout there is no need to manually get the values from the controls you can just use the values presented in the viewmodel to calculate the end date with:

```
this.computedEndDate = ko.computed(function () {
    var period = this.eventPeriod();
    var newMonth = this.eventStartDate().getMonth() + period;
    var endDate = new Date(this.eventStartDate());
    endDate.setMonth(newMonth);
    return endDate;
}, this);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtJCL/).

Anyway your original approach wouldn't work because the KO change tracking only works with observables so your original computed does not get updated when you change the inputs.

In order to also trigger the change also with the spinner buttons is not supported out of the box by KO-Kendo. However you can recreate the `kendoNumericTextBox` which can also listen to the `spin` event:

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/m3SEF/)

Comment: Thanks @nemesv. Upvoted! Thats very close to the answer I am interested in. How would I make it update real time as it is clicked? Not when focus is changed?

Comment: This is not supported by KO-Kendo out of the box, however you can "recreate" the `kendoNumericTextBox` which subscribes also on the spin event: http://jsfiddle.net/m3SEF/

Comment: @nenesv Please add that as an answer so I mark it as one. If you have a minuite, please also have a look at my other alternative below... that does not involve recreating.

Answer (score 0):

@nemesv's solution works perfectly. If you could also spare your insight @nemesv, it would be most helpful. But I was also trying to bind to the events without "recreating the NumericTextBox", so we can reuse the same logic.

It works to some extent but as I increment the months, the years seem to be incrementing too. It seems to multiply or add to the EndDate instead of the StartDate. Or I am missing something???

```
$('#EventtPeriod').ready( function() {
var eventPeriod = $("#EventPeriod").data("kendoNumericTextBox");

    eventPeriod.bind("spin", function() {

    var startControl = $('#StartDate').data('kendoDatePicker');
    //var endControl = $('#EndDate').data('kendoDatePicker');    
    var value = this.value();
    var startDate = startControl.value(); 

    startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + value);   

    $('#EndDate').data('kendoDatePicker').value(startDate);

});

});
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/user919426/AtJCL/4/

Comment: First: This should be more like another question and not an answer. Second This is still not the kncokout way of doing this... Third: and your code is not working because the `setMonth` modifies the date in place. You have to make a clone of the `startControl.value()` and modify that with: 
    `var startDate = new Date(startControl.value()); ` http://jsfiddle.net/j3rx9/

Comment: I needed something we could reuse using the KendoUI elements as is without customising or recreating. 

Noted and thanks for the correction. Thought it would help me or others who may come across my question as it is related. Will do it different next time.

Am marking your answer as the answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!